# Perl - How to find out whether a request was made via proxy?

Tags: perl, http, proxy, request, environment

My question is, if its possible to find out whether a request was made via proxy or not?
Is there an environment variable i can use? 
I looked through some lists of environment variables and didn't find something useful.
Or do i have to directly read the http header for this purpose? 
E.g. As long as the 'via' field is empty no proxy was used?
Would be thankful if someone got an easy solution for this in perl.

May you have other advices to verify a user and block/filter requests that are fake visitors.

Answer (score 1):

First, use of a proxy does not mean the user is fake. It is very common inside companies to use a proxy server for security purposes. Second, not all proxy servers add a Via header so a request from a proxy might be no different than a request from the browser itself.

Comment: I know many companies use proxies. The purpose of this is not to block a user completely from the site, it's purpose should be to filter requests that weren't made by a normal physical user. Many Hitefaker programs use proxies to fake views... It should be like the filter, youtube is using to count the userviews.